# How to add a wildcard email account ( *@domain.tld ) to an Android Mail App

Tags: android, email

I have a pop email account with username = asterisk, that is

*@domain.tld

Any emails sent o domain.tld are delivered to this box by my email provider.

I log into this account with microsoft Outlook or from the web access to this account.

When I try to add this account to my Android device for an email app to check the box when I am out, like K9 mail or the stock Email app that google provides, the Android apps will not accept a *@domain.tld user name.  If I enter an email user without asterisk the email user is accepted.

Has anyone found a way to check wildcard email accounts with Android email apps?

Comment: What's your hosting provider? Most will route a catch-all to an actual POP3 account.  But Outlook has the same config?

Comment: 1and1.com An emailbox is created to which all email sent to a domain.tld is delivered. The username of the wildcard email box is asterisk, ie. *@domain.tld  When Outlook logs in or the Web Interface to the wildcard email account is used to login the user = *@domain.tld pass = password.

Comment: After testing again today, I see that the Android apps will accept the user= *@domain.tld entry. An alternate email address must be entered to use with the newly added account, like user@domain.tld as *@domain.tld is not a valid email address.